# Stash regex query

Tags: stash, regex, regular-expressions

I'm using Stash to set and retrieve a list based on channel entries.
I want to filter the list by a 'column' of data defined by a pipe-delimited set of values.

I'm having trouble though getting the regex to work.
So, for example I have the following data in my list:

```
4|4|4|4|2|2
2|2|2|2
9|9|9|2|2
2|2|2
9|9|9|2
2|6|3|4|5|9|6|7|2
```

I'm using the following regex:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="paper" parse="inward" match="#^((.*2).*)$#" against="parents"}
```

But only two of the above are being returned in the list:

```
4|4|4|4|2|2
2|6|3|4|5|9|6|7|2
```

If I test this pattern on [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/) it returns all results as expected.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening or how better to achieve this (so returns all data with 2)? I've tried simpler regex patterns  (eg `#2#` or `#2+#`) with no success.

Thanks

Cole

Answer (score 1):

Surrounding each of the values with a separator, including the start and end of the index makes matching simple and ensures you match a '2' and not '22' or '212' (for example). I tend to use `@` or `/` rather than `|` so that I don't need to escape the pipe in the regex.

```
@4@4@4@4@2@2@
@9@9@9@2@2@
etc
```

Now you can easily match a specific number with:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="paper" match="#@2@#" against="parents"}
```

Or either of two numbers:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="paper" match="#@2@|@4@#" against="parents"}
```

Or require two numbers:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="paper" match="#^(?=.*@2@)(?=.*@4@)#" against="parents"}
```

More on filtering with a custom index column here:
https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Filtering%20lists%20with%20match%20against

Comment: Thanks Mark.

Sorry but I can't seem to get this to work.
I've posted up some sample code at https://gist.github.com/cole007/0747814121ee89f14dd3 - any thoughts why this might not be working?

Cheers,

Cole

Comment: PS am using a custom function to generate the delimited variable am filtering against. Could this be affecting things?

Comment: Possibly. I commented on your gist: https://gist.github.com/cole007/0747814121ee89f14dd3

Comment: Thanks Mark - it looks like the get list is matching against the requested values, eg `MATCH #^.*(@9@).*$# AGAINST {exp:arjo_news:parents entry_id="167"}`. Tried experimenting with different parse orders, etc to no avail.

Comment: had a good luck and figured out the problem, thanks. Looks like the parse depth needed specifying. Seems to be working now, thanks!